# Celery RPC call blocks FastAPI concurrency

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, fastapi, rpc

I am working with FastAPI application which needs to perform heavy computations for calculating its answer. I've moved heavy computations to the remote machine with GPU. I use Celery to perform remote procedure call. The current solution is the following:

1. User requests my **FastAPI** endpoint method
2. Inside this method there is a call to **Celery RPC** and then `task.get()` await with timeout for the result
3. When method gets results back from RPC it sends response to the user.

My FastAPI has 32 workers on 16-core machine, but as I've figured out, all procedures are executed sequentially, which probably means that Celery `.get()` method blocks other FastAPI threads.

My code is the following:

```
#celery_worker.py
app = Celery('celery_worker', broker= f'amqp://{rabbitmq_username}:{rabbitmq_password}@{rabbitmq_host}:{rabbitmq_port}/', backend='rpc://')

@app.task
def remote_procedure(a, b):
    #some heavy computations
    return res
```

```
#main.py
from project.celery_worker import remote_procedure

RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 1.5

@app.get('/search/')
async def search(a,b):
    try:
        res = remote_procedure.apply_async((a,b), expires = RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS+0.1, retry=False).get(timeout=RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS)
    except celery.exceptions.TimeoutError:
        print('timeout')
        return {"res":"timeout"}
    return {"res":res}


def main():
    """
    Main function
    """

    uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=CONFIG['port'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is that when I send 100 requests, I expect that some of them will be computed, some of then will return with timeout, but ALL of them must return in less than 2 sec. In fact I get situation where all of them are computed in a sequential way, so for some requests I'm waiting for response for about 15 seconds, which is unacceptable.

I suspect the problem is with blocking `.get()` method, but I'm not sure. Is there an alternative which will allow me to block the current thread while waiting for the RPC results, but won't block whole FastAPI concurrency?

Comment: Don't mark your `search` function `async` if it's in fact internally blocking (as yours is).